# Using vba function to split range into even and odd

Tags: excel, vba

I'm tring to write an Excel (2013) function that would take a 1x2n range of cells and return 1xn vector of cells that are of even/odd index. So if I put some numbers in cells A1:F1 as this

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | 23 | 67 | 12 | 6 | 1 |

And put this function in A2:C2, it should return

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | 23 | 67 | 12 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 23 | 12 | 1 |  |  |  |

I wrote something like this, but it doesn't work (#Arg! error)

```
Public Function Even(X As Variant) As Variant
Dim N As Integer
N = UBound(X)
ReDim Y(N / 2)

For i = 1 To N
If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
Y(i / 2) = X(i)
End If
Next i

Even = Y
End Function
```

After @BigBen comments I've changed the code to

```
Public Function Even(X As Variant) As Variant
Dim N As Integer
N = Application.CountA(X.Value)
ReDim Y(N / 2)

For i = 1 To N
If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
Y(i / 2) = X(i)
End If
Next i

Even = Y
End Function
```

It now returns almost what I want, it returns:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | 23 | 67 | 12 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 23 | 12 | 1 |  |  |

where's 0 coming from

Comment: @BigBen 2013 64 bit

Comment: How do you define `X` in your test? What is the output you get from `Even`?

Comment: What, exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? the wrong numbers are returned? Smoke comes out of the computer?

Comment: You're going to need to enter this (once it's working) as an array formula, with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. You could also just use regular formulas (still entered with C+S+E) to do this btw.

Comment: my guess is that you are calling this from the worksheet and `X` is a range and not a variant array.  Ranges do not have a UBound().

Comment: If you're working with a multi-cell `Range`, note that its `.Value` is a 2D array, not a 1D array.

Comment: How to you call the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility. `EVEN` is a spreadsheet function, so a different name is preferable. `EveryOther` seems natural, but with a name like that, why not make it flexible enough to select the odds if need be? A good way to do that is to make an optional Boolean argument which controls if even or odd indices are chosen:

```
Function EveryOther(Rng As Range, Optional Evens As Boolean = True) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim returnVals As Variant
    
    n = Rng.Cells.count
    ReDim returnVals(1 To n)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    
    For Each cell In Rng.Cells
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 2 = IIf(Evens, 0, 1) Then
            j = j + 1
            returnVals(j) = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    ReDim Preserve returnVals(1 To j)
    EveryOther = returnVals
End Function
```